# Is it possible to have load on start up Servlet and a normal Request, Response Servlet in same web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

For an implementation of client and server, I need to have on servlet to be started soon after deploying, another one should wait for the request. Is it possible? If what is right way to implement it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>WiCodeRedeemRequest</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WiCodeRedeemRequest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.wicode.redeem.WiCodeRedeemRequest</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WiCode</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wicode.redeem.WiCode</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>Group</param-name>
          <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>Instance</param-name>
          <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WiCodeRedeemRequest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WiCode</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Above is my web.xml. I have seen somewhere usage of listener.

I am new to servlet. Need help please.

Comment: in your xml file you have two servlet but one servlet mapping and the url-pattern and the servlet-name all are confusing.

Comment: The second servlet, WiCode which is something i don't want to run on request basis, that's why i didn't put mapping..Acutally i need it to run as a background thread..

Comment: Why not load on startup for WiCodeRedeemRequest as 1 and WiCode as 2?

Comment: All servlets wait for requests. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Small template xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.wicode.redeem.WiCodeRedeemRequest</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MappingForFirstServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wicode.redeem.WiCode</servlet-class>
     //What ever you want to initialize..
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Mapping URL</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Above example is ok. I agree all servlets waits for request.But i don't want a client to access the Servlet WiCode.(It is an initializer basically). When i put like the way i given, it's is not working; no errors on tomcat logs, port is listening..but it is not accepting any request..

Comment: Yes tomcat wont give you any error because syntactically,  you are correct. I am still not understanding what you are basically trying to do. Even creating many servlets is not a good idea. As these are costly process, Each servlet will be having there own life cycle etc. Now the container should manage all those, So, my suggestion is why don't you create a single servlet that takes all the incoming request and then based on the request it directs it to corresponding controllers. In short I am asking you to design a Front Controlled MVC Design Pattern.

Comment: Actually i have to manage a client implementation also in my app server. Basically what i am trying to achieve is it can act as a server as well as client; both are independent; The second servlet which i don't want a url mapping, it should  be able to talk to another third party interface using tcp. Also request to this servlet is coming as tcp raw data from another interface. Basically application has to talk to multiple interface and also should be able to deal with both request and responses.